# Adding custom metadata to binary files

Tags: java, metadata

How to include a custom metadata with a files without using a database to extract later using **Apache Tika** The files extension are *.doc .docx .pdf .txt .... *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be dong using PDFBox

this is an example on github with it's description on medium

https://github.com/enisinanaj/pdfbox-metadata-example

https://medium.com/@enisinanaj/how-to-write-custom-metadata-to-a-pdf-document-in-java-with-pdfbox-f52a82ab1b09

just add the Main method and call `insertMetadata()`

to set a costume metadata use

```
info.setCustomMetadataValue("ispublished", "true");
```